# How to send files between two pc

Tags: java, file-upload, download

I want to write a Java code, which will send a simple text file between two computers via internet. I know i must have a client which send a file using specified Ip address and some server. I also hava a Google App Engine. I have been looking for some examples but i haven't found anything. Could you give me some simple example or somethig ?

Comment: So, you want to send a file from my machine to your machine without my knowledge and participation in sending that file? It might contain information that I would not have agreed to sending you?

Comment: Who would trigger the transfer, the client or the server?

Comment: I want to write an app which will synchronize file on two computers and it's going to work only when two users have client and server run on their computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html
from Java tutorial is a good point to start with

Answer (score 1):

I think the example you are following will work also over the internet but you have to tune it  setting the right value of ip-address,

```
Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1",13267);
```

127.0.0.1 is your localhost, you should set it as the ip of the server machine.

The point is that if you have some particular network setting (such NAT) or some firewall impostation it could be a little more difficult to do this.